# Does session-based authentication break the stateless architecture constraint of a REST web API?

Tags: api, rest, stateless

I'm designing a REST web API using Django REST Framework and I'm using session-based (for AJAX) and token-based authentication for mobile clients (Android).

But I'm wondering wether the session-based authentication isn't breaking the RESTful architecture constraint of being "stateless"? Because it does add a layer of "state" in the API? But on the other hand, using token-based authentication for AJAX calls doesn't seem like a good idea to me either, because then you should store the token in JavaScript?

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication

Kind regards,
K.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet might serve as a reference

Comment: Still not sure about this: Django [stores session information on the server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions), but Fielding's dissertation mentions stateless-server as one of the first constraints ([section 5.1.3](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1)): "... each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reference! :-)

From the reference:

*"RESTful web services should use session-based authentication, either by establishing a session token via a POST or by using an API key as a POST body argument or as a cookie."*

Using the default settings for authentication in Django (login and logout) there is a cookie set "sessionid" when you login. I have my REST API configured with global permision "IsAuthenticated", so I guess the REST API uses the cookie to detemrine the session.

So all of this seems in line with the REST architecture contraints. :-)